# Image compression react native

Tags: react-native, expo

My app sends images from gallery and camera to my backend server. I want to compress these images to minimize the storage usage. how can I do that?

PS: I am using Expo.

Answer (score 0):

When you pick the image from the gallery, we can specify a *quality* option.

Cf  documentation https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/#arguments

Or this is only a storage problem, we may also compress the image with your backend, but the solution depends of your backend.